# listing ticket prices in front of provided options in python

Tags: python, arrays, list

im writing this code as practice for wildlife park to sell tickets. i need to place the prices of each available option in front of the option but cant figure out how to do it.
this is the code:

```
tickettype = ['one adult', 'onechild', 'one senior', 'family ticket', 'group of six or more']
cost1day = [20,12,16,60, 15]

for A in tickettype:
    print(A)
for B in cost1day:
    print(B)
```

its output is like this

```
one adult
onechild
one senior
family ticket
group of six or more
20
12
16
60
15
```

whereas i need  both list aligned in front of each other.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an option.

```
tickettype = ['one adult', 'onechild', 'one senior', 'family ticket', 'group of six or more']
cost1day = [20,12,16,60, 15]

for A,B in zip(tickettype,cost1day):
    print(A+":"+str(b))
```